# Call to a member function on a non-object php ci

Tags: php, codeigniter

Excuse me master, I had an error in my controller, I'm a newbie PHP CI programmer.
Can you help me where is my mistake on this code? The error says : "Call to a member function produk_list() on a non-object"

And here's my code on my controller :

```
function index()
{
    $data = array();
    $data['template'] = 'produk/index'; 
    $data['query'] = $this->produk_model->produk_list($this->uri->segment(4),5,true);       
    $data['page_title'] = 'Produk';

    $this->pagination->initialize(paging_admin($this->produk_model->count(true),'admin/produk/index'));
    $data['pagination'] =  $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data['breadcrum'] = array(array("MIS Admin Panel",'admin'),
                               array('Produk','admin/produk'),
                               array('List','')
                         );

    $data = array_merge($data,admin_info());
    $this->parser->parse('admin/index',$data);
}
```

And here's my code on my models (produk_model)

```
function produk_list($limit,$offset,$admin = false)
{
    if($admin === false) $this->db->select('id,title,image,content,created_at');
    if($admin === false) $this->db->where('publish',1);
    $this->db->order_by('id','DESC');
    ($limit == '')? $this->db->limit($offset,0) : $this->db->limit($offset,$limit);
    $query = $this->db->get('produk');  
    if($admin === false){
        $data = array();
        foreach($query->result() as $row){
            $data[] = array('produkid' => $row->id,
                            'produktitle' => $row->title,
                            'produkurltitle' => url_title($row->title,'dash',true),
                            'produkdate' => human_date_time($row->created_at),
                            'produkfrontdate' => human_date($row->created_at),
                            'produkimage' => ($row->image != '')? '<img src="{produk_tpath}'.$row->image.'" alt="'.$row->title.'" title="'.$row->title.'" />' : '',
                            'produkcontent' => character_limiter(strip_tags($row->content),200),
                            );
        }
        return $data;
    }else{
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

Thank you master...
Hope you can help me...

Comment: The error message contained a line number. You'll need to add that.

Comment: is the model `produk_model`  loaded?

Comment: I think model not loaded in controller

Comment: @Pekka웃 : thank guys, I currently added a line number

Comment: tomsexans and Adarsh : yes I forgot to load my model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must either load the model in your controller or autoload the model in `autoload.php` under config before calling the model function

```
$this->load->model('produk_model');
```